# Morph fails to remove in IE 8/9

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on an Ember app (using RC1) and am having a problem with IE (surprise).  We have a series of nested views that can show either a trip's summary, details, or edit.  The trip view looks (roughly) like this:

```
{{#if tripController.showSummary}}
    {{template "view/TripSummaryView"}}
{{/if}}

{{#if tripController.showDetails}}
    {{template "view/TripDetailView"}}
{{/if}}

{{#if tripController.showEdit}}
    {{template "view/TripEditView"}}
{{/if}}
```

On the div surrounding the trip summary view, I have an action:

```
<div {{bindAttr id="tripController.tripId"}} 
     class="card single-line" 
     {{action "toggleDetails" tripController on="click"}} 
     style="cursor:pointer">
```

And the controller handles the action:

```
toggleDetails: function(tripController) {
    if (this.get('showDetails')) {
        this.set('showDetails', false);
        this.set('showSummary', true);
    } else {
        this.set('showDetails', true);
        this.set('showSummary', false);
    }
},
```

All pretty vanilla, and it works perfectly in Chrome, FF, and Safari. But when I run it in IE, it bombs in the metamorph's realNode() function (line 17264 in ember.js):

```
var realNode = function(start) {
    while (start.parentNode.tagName === "") {
      start = start.parentNode;
    }

    return start;
  };
```

with this error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'parentNode': object is null or undefined
```

When I put a breakpoint in the code, it appears that Ember is trying to remove 2 metamorphs, but that the second is inside the first and so `start` is null the second time around.  I put a breakpoint in that function in Chrome, but it doesn't ever appear to get called.

I've tried reducing this down to a JSFiddle, but I can't seem to get it to break - so there must be something in the way we've got our views set up that's causing a problem.  Any suggestions on how to go about debugging this would be most appreciated!

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Well, I haven't figured out why this code was failing in IE,but by changing the {{template}} helpers to {{view}} helpers, it started to work.  It seems like there's some IE bug in Ember with the {{template}} helper, but unfortunately I can't seem to reproduce without our full codebase

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using ContainerView but I am also facing similar problem where childviews are not receiving model/controller. Here is a [similar post] ([An example of ContainerView required where childViews are binded with their respective controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097868/an-example-of-containerview-required-where-childviews-are-binded-with-their-resp) "containerview's childviews controller binding")